# Why can't I import PyQt in Python files?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pycharm

I have installed PyQt using brew but when I am trying to import it, I just receive errors as follows:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt5
```

Here's the command I used in terminal for installing PyQt in OSX:

```
brew install python qt pyqt pyside pyside-tools
```

Any idea what's gone wrong?

Comment: I am curious, you can't use `pip`?

Comment: see if this helps: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Comment: why did you install both `pyqt` and `pyside`? what version of `Python` are you using?

Comment: Are you actually running the brew Python, instead of the Apple pre-installed Python or some other Python? Each one has its own site-packages, and you've only installed PyQt for one of them.

Comment: @abarnert can you explain further with more details? I can't seem to be able to follow

Comment: How are you running Python? If you're using the command line, what command did you type? And if it's just `python`, what does `which python` say? If you're using an IDE, how did you configure the IDE? If none of that makes sense to you, try `import os, sys`, `print(sys.executable)`, `print(sys.version)`, `print(os.__file__)` and that should give us enough information to figure out the answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

The most painless way to do python without messing around with modules is to install distributions. Two very good ones are [Canopy Python](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) and [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). They have most, if not all, modules you are going to need for production. Pyqt and pyside are included in both of these distributions.

Comment: I need to access PyQt within PyCharm. What's the solution?